# MotionEvent Initialize?

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I'm trying to call the onTouch method from a different class but I have no idea what to pass in for MotionEvent. Using null makes the app force close. Heres the code

```
public final class Touch {

private static final String TAG = Touch.class.getSimpleName();

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, Droid droid, Thread thread) {
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
{
    droid.handleActionDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
    /*if (event.getY() > getHeight() - 50) 
    {
        thread.setRunning(false);
        ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
    } 
    else 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + event.getX() + ",y=" + event.getY());
    }*/
} 
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) 
{
    // the gestures
    if (droid.isTouched()) 
    {
        // the droid was picked up and is being dragged
        droid.setX((int)event.getX());
        droid.setY((int)event.getY());
    }
} 
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
{
    // touch was released
    if (droid.isTouched()) 
    {
        droid.setTouched(false);
    }
}
return true;
}
}
```

Thats the class, how would I call that in the main thread? Currently I'm trying:

```
public void Touch()
{
    MotionEvent event = null;
    touch.onTouchEvent(event, droid, thread);
}
```

As null is the only thing that I can think of to pas in.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, x, y, metaState);
```

Comment: I dont have any of those variables declared, not really sure how to use that.

Comment: MotionEvent.obtain(1, 1, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, -5, -5, 1) as an example. I genrate those values for fake drag